# BlazorWASM: Email disappears on DisplayLogin

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, webapi, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am trying to do JWT Authentication, I have BlazorWASM (asp.net core hosted)
I have created a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.

After logging in the user, I got this as expected:

[image]

But after re-rendering the use name disappears, but still I have access to authorised resources

```
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }
        var userInfo = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<LoginResponse>("UserInfo"); 
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) }, "apiauth"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
```

Notice that I am only storing the token.
And this is the Login Method

```
    public async Task<Response<LoginResponse>> Login(LoginRequest loginModel)
    {
        var loginAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginModel);
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/Account/Login", new StringContent(loginAsJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var loginResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response<LoginResponse>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return loginResult;
        }

        await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", loginResult.Data.JWToken);
        ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginModel.Email);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", loginResult.Data.JWToken);
        return loginResult;
    }
```

to be more specific, call `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` cause the same result (username disappears).

So what should I do?

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to display authenticated user name?

Comment: @marc_S
the same default "LoginDisplay" component 

`<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            
            Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
            <a href="LogOut">Log out</a>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Login">Log in</a>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>`